# FileOutputStream java.io.IOException: Premature EOF

Tags: java, spring, apache, jax-ws, webservice-client

I have client Java application that contact central server and get media files from there. There are more then 200 such clients. But only one reported this error. When I try on my developer machine it is working without problems. Also it is tried in one more machine, also without error. On both machines same content is downloaded, which is problematic on that specific machine. Root of error is line 33

Code

```
30 protected File downloadFile(DataHandler fileData, String temporaryFileNamePrefix) throws IOException {
31    File file = File.createTempFile(temporaryFileNamePrefix, "zip");
32    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
33    fileData.writeTo(fout);
34    fout.flush();
35    fout.close();
36    return file;
37 }
```

DataHandler is from javax.activation.DataHandler

On web service it is declared like this:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlMimeType("application/octet-stream")
private javax.activation.DataHandler fileData;
```

Exception:

```
08 Oct 01:50:48,729 ERROR  
java.io.IOException: Premature EOF
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAheadBlocking(ChunkedInputStream.java:538)
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAhead(ChunkedInputStream.java:582)
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:669)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:116)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:2668)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:169)
    at org.apache.cxf.attachment.MimeBodyPartInputStream.read(MimeBodyPartInputStream.java:77)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:82)
    at org.apache.cxf.attachment.DelegatingInputStream.read(DelegatingInputStream.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.helpers.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:135)
    at org.apache.cxf.helpers.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:103)
    at org.apache.cxf.attachment.AttachmentDataSource.cache(AttachmentDataSource.java:49)
    at org.apache.cxf.attachment.AttachmentDeserializer.cacheStreamedAttachments(AttachmentDeserializer.java:229)
    at org.apache.cxf.attachment.AttachmentDeserializer.hasNext(AttachmentDeserializer.java:339)
    at org.apache.cxf.attachment.LazyAttachmentCollection.hasNext(LazyAttachmentCollection.java:77)
    at org.apache.cxf.attachment.AttachmentDeserializer.markClosed(AttachmentDeserializer.java:323)
    at org.apache.cxf.attachment.DelegatingInputStream.close(DelegatingInputStream.java:47)
    at org.apache.cxf.attachment.DelegatingInputStream.close(DelegatingInputStream.java:45)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:297)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy174.processQueItem(Unknown Source)
    at 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Problematic machine is running on Windows, with Java 6 on Tomcat. Data are fetched with jaxws Spring implementation. Server is on Linux with Java 8 on Tomcat with 2 nodes.

Does anyone experienced similar issue and knows what can be a problem? 
Plus would be if someone knows how this error can be recreated.

Comment: I'm missing something.  You attribute the error to what appears to be a write, but the stack trace characterizes a read error.

Comment: I found someone talking about a similar issue. While I dont exactly understand why its only happening on this one machine, their proposed solution was to not use a buffered reader object, and to read one byte at a time while in a try/catch for the EOF. Then again, this assumes that the issue is really on a read, and not related to the write as you claim above.

Comment: Also, when you say "On both machines same content is downloaded," I suppose you must mean that both clients *request* the same content, since it appears that downloading the data is exactly the problem.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I read in some other posts that this error can be misleading. But first line in stacktrace comming from my class is one I referenced here.All others mine classes in st are just callers of that line.Yes it means both machines on which I was able to test requested same content, and flow is finished without error.@Mark I can't change easy anything before I am sure what is going on because on 199 others this works correctly.And when I change something patch will be available to all other clients, so I don't want to introduce some new problems.I must first somehow try on my machine.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I updated question with more info. So before this call there are read for sure. It is read from web server. When fileData.writeTo(fout) is called it must read from fileData and write to fout under the hood.

Comment: I don't see `downloadFile` in your stack trace - are you sure this method is where the problem is?